# Issue with pop_back() not removing vector elements c++

Tags: c++, vector

I hope this isn't a duplicate question, but I can't find an answer on here that solves my issue.

I've created a 2D vector of a fixed row and column length, and then filled it with information from a simulation I ran. I purposely set the row length to be much longer than necessary, as some of my simulations generate more data than others.

All I want to do is remove the rows from my vector that weren't given any data. Here is my code:

```
int states = 13;
int duration = 1000;
vector<int> temp(states, -1);

vector<vector<int> > state_data(duration, temp);
    //Fill in some number of the rows
    int x=0;
    while(condition){
        state_data[x][1] = 3;    
        ...
        state_data[x][13] = 10;
        x++;
    }    

    for(int i =0; i < (state_data.size()-x+1); i++){
        state_data.pop_back();
    }

    // Also have tried this:
    // state_data.erase(x, state_data.size());
    return state_data;
}
```

The `pop_back` version doesn't give an error, but doesn't remove the rows. The erase function gives an error regardless if I try to remove 1 or multiple at a time: `"candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided"` and also `"no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::vector<int> >::erase(int)"`.

All of the answers I've found for erasing have given answers using these two functions, and I can't figure out why neither are doing what I want in this case. I really appreciate any advice you can give on why these functions aren't doing what I want!

Comment: First `state_data[x][13] = 10;` is undefined as you are going past the end of the vector.  Secondly how is `pop_back()` not working?  Please provide and [mcve]

Comment: Note that the value of `state_data.size()` changes as the loop executes. There exists a `resize` function – use `state_data.resize(x)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the problem you're experiencing with pop_back is that the size is changing at every pop. Consider, if x were 5 and the vector size is 10, you plan on removing 5 elements, leaving 0 through 4.

At first, size - 5 + 1 is 6, i is zero, the loop's block executes, i will be incremented to 1.

At that point, size - 5 + 1 will be 5, i is 1, the loop continues.
This proceeds with 4 against i==2, then 3 when i==3. The loop will terminate.

At that point the container size will be 7. You wanted it to be five, but since the size decreases at each pop, the 'counter' is approaching a shrinking limit. You should calculate size - 5 + 1 before the loop, store that as 'lim' or something you like, use that within the for loop for the test against i. It may be better to look up the resize function for vector, it would do this for you.

Further, take care about the limits of the vectors you create and your accesses using [], especially the line

```
state_data[x][13] = 10;
```

You allocated room for 13 entries, but INDEX 13 is the 14th entry. Vectors aren't extended with the [] operator, so that should crash.

You may want to consider std::array for some design choices, instead of vector, especially for the interior vector in your design, as they are lighter, fixed sized allocations.

Now, about this notion of creating rows and then removing them later. That's not really necessary. There are two possible solutions that are better.

First, consider using reserve as opposed to pop. Pop may not do what you think anyway. It will remove rows, decreasing the length of items known to be in the vector, but it doesn't guarantee STORAGE will be reduced (same for resize when shrinking). A block of RAM is allocated dynamically at creation, or reallocated at extension, but vector may not shrink STORAGE any as you pop. The actual storage it occupies may remain the same, which would be the same result as if you issued a reserve of storage ahead of time, and did push_backs of the data to populate.

If the reason you initialized several rows more than required, and pop afterwards, was not about storage strategy but instead about using the [], you should reconsider and use push_back instead, so you avoid the performance penalty and additional complexity of popping all the 'extra' rows you didn't need in the first place.

This is one of the times when a deque may be a better choice. Deques do respond to "shrinking", function much like vectors in many respects, but allow for pushing and popping at both ends of structure, with more flexible storage internally.

You could use a deque as the container of rows (the outer container), and possibly std::array as the interior container of each fixed sized row.

That might look like:

```
std::deque<std::array<int, 13> > state_data(duration, temp);
```

Or something similar, perhaps still vector as the interior storage, depending on flexibility requirements

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The size value changing was definitely what I was missing. I was originally allocating so much extra, rather than using push_back(), because I didn't know that function existed -- I'm new to c++. I'm now going to use push_back instead which solves all problems. I really appreciate your answer and time. Also, the indexing problem was simply a typo in my question, and not a typo in my code -- I stil haven't figured out how to copy my text from vim and get it into other programs.

Comment: Sure. Would you consider 'accepting' the answer so I get some rep points for it?